# What is the API class that i might have to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

```
irb(main):006:0> @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new
```

KOALA: Deprecation warning: Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI is deprecated and will be
removed in a future version; please use the API class instead.
=> #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new
```

all of the classes are aliased from GraphAPI over to API